# Extract gallery ID from HTML PHP

Tags: php, html, variables, extract

I have a variable named `$html`:

```
$html = '<li class="col">[gallery_id=234]</li>';
```

I want to get `gallery_id` (in this case - 234) into another variable from `$html`.

Comment: that looks like a decently random variable format. might have to parse that one on your own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy. Just use regex with [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/preg_match):

```
$html = '<li class="col">[gallery_id=234]</li>';
preg_match("/\[gallery_id=([0-9].*)\]/is", $html, $matches);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

I have that `print_r` in there for debugging/illustration purposes. It would return the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [gallery_id=234]
    [1] => 234
)
```

Then to access the result you want, just do this:

```
echo $matches[1];
```

The returned value will be:

> 234

Answer (score 0):

```
$html = '<li class="col">[gallery_id=234]</li>';
preg_match('!\d+!', $html, $var);
echo $var[0]; //echoes 234
```

Comment: The question asks for the gallery id, not just any number in the string. I agree that your code works for this particular sample, but it's not very robust...

Comment: Ok, but the question is not very robust either.  Thanks for pointing it out nevertheless - the above answer is more specific.